# What breaks the html flow in css?

Tags: css, html

I'm having a few problems trying to position some `div`s in my website layout. All of them is related to the `div`'s size. I'm using Chrome's developer tools to inspect the `div`s and when I mouse over some divs it is just *1px-high*, but it has content inside and its content has some height. Shouldn't it have at least the same height of its content?

I don't know if I explained well, so I'm posting some images. I'm using **Blueprint CSS Framework** and it happens when I use `class="span-XX"` and inside it I don't use neither `class`

Here is some images (click to zoom)

The parent `div`
[image]

The `div` with problem (no height)
[image]

The child `div`
[image]

The parent `div` has `class="span-XX"`, the `div` with problem has only `#search`
which is [this one](http://pastebin.com/KjqmKrXZ)

I suspect it is some float or positioning issue with css but I don't know what it is and how to deal with it. I have also a list containing the social networks on the top of the site which `ul` has the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have floats inside, you need to clear them. Apply `overflow:hidden; zoom:1;` to the parent containing the floats and it should resolve it.

If you have negative margins / position + relative and negative offset and cant use overflow hidden use a clearfix... http://work.arounds.org/clearing-floats/

Comment: It really worked! The **Blueprint CSS Framework** already has the `clearfix` class, I just had to apply it into the `div`. But why doesn't it work on **unordered lists**? Both menu and social network's `<ul>` is 1px-high. Yes, `<li>` inside them are floated

Answer (score 1):

Your child div has the float property set, so the parent div will not expand height-wise to contain it. To get the behavior you expect, set overflow: hidden on the parent div.